# Problem in invoking a Workflow from Windows service.. stuck at waitHandle.WaitOne();

Tags: windows-services, workflow-foundation

please look into the below code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Workflow.Runtime;

namespace TestWinService
{
    public partial class TestWorkflowService : ServiceBase
    {
        StreamWriter sw;

        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        WorkflowRuntime workflowRuntime;
        AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public TestWorkflowService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
            sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\newFileForTest.txt", true);
            dict.Add("OperationType", "+");
            dict.Add("Num1", 10);
            dict.Add("Num2", 20);
            workflowRuntime = new WorkflowRuntime();

            WorkflowInstance instance = workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(WorkflowLibrary1.Workflow1), dict);
            instance.Start();
            sw.WriteLine("Workflow Instance started at : " + DateTime.Now);

            waitHandle.WaitOne(); // STUCK HERE.. Control is not moving at all

            sw.Write("waitHandle.WaitOne() passed");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            workflowRuntime.WorkflowCompleted += delegate(object sender, WorkflowCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("The result is : " + e.OutputParameters["Result"]);
                sw.Write("Service stopped at : " + DateTime.Now);               
                waitHandle.Set();
            };            
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

A simple window service invoking a workflow but it is getting stuck at waitHandle.WaitOne();

The same runs fine from Console Application. Am I missing something or there is a different way to do so.. please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are not wiring up the workflow event that sets the wait handle until your OnStop method.  The workflow I assume is running OK?  It is just completing, and never setting the wait handle because you don't have a listener for the completed event yet.  Wire up the event as soon as you create the workflow runtime.